# C++ - Converting between string and LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am trying to write a function to convert a string to a LPCWSTR.  Here's what I have:

```
LPCWSTR stoLPCWSTR(string str)
{
    wstring w(str.begin(), str.end());
    return w.c_str();
}
```

I've run this code with debugging, and at the return line, the transmitted string sits safely in w.  However, when it returns, it looks something like this:

"ﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮꑯ䎕骙ᰀ䪀ɽ绐ɽ▼ཛĖ"

...so basically, garbage.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wide string, `w`, goes out of scope at the end of the function and is destroyed.

The value returned by `c_str()` no longer points to valid data.

Return the wide-string instead, and use `c_str()` on it only at the location it is needed.

```
wstring stows(string str)
{
    return wstring(str.begin(), str.end());
}

//...

wstring ws = stows("hello");

api_call_needing_LPCWSTR(ws.c_str());
```

Comment: Ok, so how can I return a valid pointer?

Answer (score 2):

You're retuning unallocated memory here; the wstring has gone out of scope and you're returning a pointer to it. That's why you get rubbish.